# Не удаётся удалить и редактировать пост ВКонтакте

Tags: вконтакте, vkontakte-api

Здравствуйте, при использовании **vkontakte API**, возникла проблема, в частности, при работе с постами. 
Вот код:

```
VK.Api.call('wall.post', {message: 'текст текст',}, function(res){console.log(res);});
```

Все работает отлично, посты успешно размещаются, но при попытке редактирования или удаления поста

```
VK.Api.call('wall.edit', {post_id: 37,  message: 'текст текст', owner_id: 216270054}, function(res){console.log(res);});
```

пост не редактируется и выдаётся ошибка с кодом 20 и содержанием:

> Permission to perform this action is denied for non-standalone applications: you should request token using blank.html page*

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема: почему размещать пост можно без проблем, а удалять и редактировать его не получается?

Comment: > Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем проблема?

http://vk.com/dev/wall.edit - коробочка сверху

> почему размещать пост можно без проблем, а удалять и редактировать его не получается?

Вопрос к ответственным за API, можете в саппорт им написать и спросить, почему так (я серьезно)

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите на разницу в документации для методов [`wall.post`](https://vk.com/dev/wall.post) и [`wall.edit`](https://vk.com/dev/wall.edit): первый доступен «Standalone приложениям **и web-приложениям, [использующим окно подтверждения](https://vk.com/dev/api_confirm)**», а второй — только для Standalone.

Логика подсказывает, что, вероятно, ваше приложение не Standalone, а обычное веб-приложение, и поэтому ему недоступен метод `wall.edit()`.